# Im trying to remove duplicates while getting a MAX result at the same time. I cant remove the duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates, max, distinct

```
select distinct person.person_id, MAX(patient_encounter.enc_timestamp) as LastAppt 

from patient_encounter inner join person on patient_encounter.person_id = person.person_id
where enc_timestamp between '2018-04-05 00:00:00.000' and '2020-04-05 23:59:59.999' 
      and patient_encounter.person_id = person.person_id
      and billable_ind = 'y' and person.last_name <> 'ztest'
group by person.person_id, patient_encounter.enc_timestamp
order by person.person_id
```

Comment: Please include sample output and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select p.person_id, max(pe.enc_timestamp) as LastAppt     
from patient_encounter pe inner join
     person p
     on pe.person_id = p.person_id
where pe.enc_timestamp >= '2018-04-05' and
      pe.enc_timestamp < '2020-04-06' and
      ?.billable_ind = 'y' and   -- what table is this in ???
      p.last_name <> 'ztest'
group by p.person_id
order by p.person_id;
```

The `GROUP BY` specifies the definition of each row in the results  set.  This is specifying that you want one row per distinct value of `person_id`.

Notes:

- The fix is to remove the timestamp from the `GROUP BY`.
- `SELECT DISTINCT` is almost never needed with `GROUP BY`.  In fact, it is rarely needed at all.
- There is no reason to redundantly duplicate the `JOIN` conditions in the `WHERE` clause.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- You should qualify *all* column references.  What table is `billing_ind` in?
- You can simplify the date comparisons.  As a benefit, you can think in terms of days rather than milliseconds.

Comment: BEAUTIFUL! This works! thank you so much.  I added the table name that was missing.